# Windows LAN shared executable, what is the share's IP address? C11

Tags: c, windows, share, ip-address, lan

If I share an executable file written in C11 on a private class C LAN in Windows, is there any way the executable can determine it's *remote* IP address?

I'm trying to get a server/client TCP chat system working. All files are on the server, which are shared as a folder with the network. So launching a client does so from the server, and I do not want the clients to have to ask for the IP address to connect to (the server.)

Comment: So you want your executable to look up the IP address not of the machine it's running on, but the one the *file* is on?  Without passing it any information?  I don't think there's a straightforward way to do this... I guess you could check the executable's path to find the name of the share, then try to find the IP from that (from your local machine's perspective)...

Comment: Using Windows file sharing?  No problem; GetModuleFileName.  If the program was launched using a UNC path the first element will be either an IP address or a DNS name.  If it was launched using a mapped drive you'll need to look up the network path using WNetGetConnection.